# How can i use variable on the previous page

Tags: php, forms

I have a form for search user on like `index.php?topic=pagename`

I assign to variable what i wrote search form. So like ;

```
$name= $_POST['username'];
```

Everything okay, i can run this query on same page.

But i want to add new query under the previous query's result.

So like ;

`$name` have 5 euro.

Add money : NEW FORM

I can add form for add new money to under the previous query echo's. It seems. And it runs but i cant use previous variable `$name` .

Btw, add money form run on same page

Answer (score 0):

What about just storing that value in a hidden input in the new form?

```
// new form
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $name ?>"/>
```

Comment: Is this option cookie free? Might be a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try $_SESSION:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

or $_COOKIE:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions for this.

Store data in session, then use it in previous page.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp